# Doctrine ORM: how can I fetch distinct Embedded?

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, distinct

Let's say that we are in the following situation:

```php
/**
 * This is a Doctrine Embeddable
 */
class MyEmbeddable {
  private $_field1;
  private $_field2;
}

/**
 * This is a Doctrine Entity and is mapped to a table
 */
class MyEntity {
  private int $_id;
  private string $_name;

  // Different `MyEntities` can have a `MyEmbeddable` containing exactly the same data
  private MyEmbeddable $_embedded;
}
```

Let's suppose that the DB table is the following:

```
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | name           | embedded_field1 | embedded_field2 |
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  1 | an_entity_name |      some_value |              42 |
+----+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I know that I can fetch all `MyEntitie`s with the following code:

```php
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$q = $qb->select('e')
        ->from(MyEntity::class, 'e')
        ->where(...)
        ->getQuery();

print_r($q->getResult()); // An `array` of `MyEntitie`s
```

And I know how to use `->distinct()` to filter potential duplicate values arising from `JOIN`s.

But how can I fetch all `DISTINCT` `MyEmbeddable`s of `MyEntity`-es? What I have tried:

```php
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$q = $qb->select('e._embedded')
        ->distinct()
        ->from(MyEntity::class, 'e')
        ->where(...)
        ->getQuery();

print_r($q->getResult());
// error `MyEntity has no field or association named _embedded`
```